# Passing Nodes as parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm passing an Node type element to cardClicked.

```
 function init() {
     for (i in set.cards) {
         var myP = document.createElement("p");
         myP.innerHTML = set.cards[i].points + "&nbsp &nbsp" + set.cards[i].name;
         myP.addEventListener("click", cardClicked.bind(myP));
         document.getElementById("left column").appendChild(myP);
     }
 }


 function cardClicked(myP) {
     document.getElementById("right column").appendChild(myP);
 }
```

But when I run this code the browser says that `myP` is not of type Node and can't be added via `appendChild`?

What's going on?

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to run? I don't see anything in that code that would cause `myP` to not be a Node. Although you should consider not using a `for..in` loop for arrays (assuming `set.cards` is an array).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two variables called `myP`:

1. `var myP`
2. `cardClicked(myP)`

Because you called `cardClicked.bind(myP)`, the value of `this` inside `cardClicked` will be **1** (which it would have been anyway because of the way event handlers work).

The value of 2 is still going to be the first argument passed when `cardClicked` is called, and that will be the event object (which, as the error message says, is not a Node).

Use `this` instead.

---

```
 function init() {
     var i, myP;
     for (i in set.cards) {
         myP = document.createElement("p");
         myP.innerHTML = set.cards[i].points + "&nbsp; &nbsp;" + set.cards[i].name;
         myP.addEventListener("click", cardClicked);
         document.getElementById("left column").appendChild(myP);
     }
 }

 function cardClicked(event) {
     document.getElementById("right column").appendChild(this);
 }
```